Can you introduce nuclei into QED as elementary particles with charge $+Ze$?
If we'd like to look at the interaction between nuclei and electrons using QED - e.g., let's say we want to describe the hydrogen molecule - could we introduce the hydrogen nuclei as another "elementary" field with spin 1/2 and charge $+e$?
In principle, to fully describe the interaction, we would need to consider that nuclei are made of quarks and include their strong and weak nuclear interactions. However, for the description of molecules (rather than nuclear structure), it seems that the electromagnetic component would be the most important, so we should in some sense be able to neglect the other forces. Is this intuition correct?
I know that one can add nuclei simply as a static Coulomb field (I think this is done e.g. in the calculation of the Lamb shift), but that seems to me quite unsatisfatory from a theoretical viewpoint. Also, we would clearly be losing corrections coming from nuclear motion and probably smaller relativistic effects.

What you're saying is essentially effective field theory

It's similar to the parton model analysis really, depending on the energy either you're doing coherent (quasi)-elastic scattering or you are doing (shallow) deep inelastic scattering. And all regions are already well under investigation, there are even PDFs for nucleons as there are for their parton constituents.

There were attempts to generalize the Bethe-Salpeter equation to more than two (and possibly different) spin $1/2$ particles.
